# How to use R to get drift rate and volatility rate of stock prices changes?

Tags: r, time-series, stochastic-processes

I am doing a research on the historical annual stock prices changes, where I have about 30 rows of annual stock prices. How can I use R to get the drift and volatility rate?

Comment: There are two parts of the problem. First, choosing a model for stock returns. Second, implementing that in `R`. Do you have any ideas for the first part? What have you tried so far? By the way, *30 rows* means thirty companies' stock prices for $T$ years or one company's stock price for 30 years?

Comment: I am using geometric Brownian motion, and 30 rows means one company's stock price for 30 years. So far I tried to get the volatility rate for the data, but I have no idea how to do the drift rate.

Comment: I do not have experience with continuous time financial modelling, but rather discrete time like ARIMA+GARCH. Perhaps `sde` package in R could work for you? There are some functions for Brownian motion etc.